# Adjusting the Boundary Condition Locations for the 1D Wave Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

I'm trying to solve the non-dimensional 1D wave equation:

$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}$

subject to the homogenous Dirichlet boundary conditions. However the interval for the problem is not the usual $0\leq x \leq L$, but rather $-4 \leq x \leq 5$.

Can I adjust this range by shifting it +4 so that it goes from $0\leq x \leq 9$ and use that as the location of the boundaries? Using the original BCs seems to lead to a more tedious and involved solution.

Boundary Conditions:

$u(-4,t)=u(5,t)=0$

Initial Conditions:

$u(x,0)=sin(\pi x) $ for $ 0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0$ everywhere else.

$\frac{\partial u(x,0)}{\partial t} = 0$

Comment: You might state the bc if they are causing trouble.

Comment: The boundary conditions are $u(-4,t)=u(5,t)=0$.

Comment: You really improved the question now, good!

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: I think I have the right solution. It looks good when plotted at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since your equation does not depend on $x$.
You have to shift the initial condition, though, since it depends on $x$. Use $$u(x,0)=\sin(\pi(x+4))$$ on $4\leq x \leq 5$ and $0$ everywhere else. Of course, if you shift the equation, you have to shift the initial condition as well. The solution will also be shifted into the new domain, obviously.

I hope I got your question right now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/535212)

Comment: Thats all i can give without knowing the bc

Comment: So put it in the comment below the question! :)

Comment: Sorry, but in general he can shift the equation, also the boundary condition, therefore I provided an answer. I also asked for the bc now to improve this answer.

Comment: Feel free to convince yourself that I give detailed answers whenever I feel they are necessary.

Comment: OK, I really didn't mean to be offensive! :) Sorry if it seemed that way! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32381/discussion-between-tomglabst-and-h-r).